# smart contract recovery

Tags: recovery

Good morning.

i tried to participate to a smart contract yesterday and unfortunatly i have been front-run by other users. So, on the 50 users max, i was 51/50. Bad luck. My problem is that my ethereum arrived on the smart contract address and i want to get my money back.
Is it possible to do a reverse transaction using metamask nonce option ?
i hope you will understand me.
Sorry for my english, i'm french.
Thanks by advance.
Bests regards

---

the person who recommended that I subscribe to this smart contract told me that it was possible to make a recovery at a different address from the one at which I subscribed. To do this, you need to send a certain number of ETH to be able to recover the first and second for a fee.

Comment: No there's no option to reverse, if the contract has a recovery option then you can get them back.

Answer (score 1):

GM.

Ethereum transactions are irreversible once they are confirmed and included in a block. Metamask's nonce option would only help in ensuring that subsequent transactions are properly sequenced but not reverse transaction.

Recommend you to review the smart contract's logic to see if there are any mechanisms for withdrawing funds or recovering funds in case of failed transactions. If the smart contract you interacted with has a mechanism to refund unused funds, you might receive your funds back automatically when the smart contract execution completes.

Have a good day.